# SQLAlchemy fails when adding literal_column

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using Flask-SQLAlchemy and Postgres, and I have 2 classes `FacebookPost` and `TwitterPost` which I want to query 2 columns from, add a 3rd column `post_type` to denote which class they are from, union the results, and then sort them.

When I construct the two subqueries (without the `post_type` column) and union them like so

```
t1 = FacebookPost.__table__
fbq = db.session.query(t1.c.provider_post_id, t1.c.created_at).\
    join(FacebookPage).join((Artist,FacebookPage.artists)).\
    filter(Artist.id == 1).order_by(FacebookPost.created_at.desc()).\
    limit(5)
t2 = TwitterPost.__table__
twq = db.session.query(t2.c.provider_post_id, t2.c.created_at)\
    .join(TwitterUser).join((Artist,TwitterUser.artists)).\
    filter(Artist.id == 1).order_by(TwitterPost.created_at.desc()).\
    limit(5)
u = union(fbq.subquery().select(), twq.subquery().select())
db.session.query('provider_post_id', 'created_at').select_from(u).\
    order_by("created_at desc").all()
```

This works compeltely fine and as you'd expect. As soon as I update my two queries to include the `post_type` like so

```
fbq = db.session.query(t1.c.provider_post_id, t1.c.created_at,\
    literal("facebook_post", type_=db.String).label("post_type")).\
    join(FacebookPage).join((Artist,FacebookPage.artists)).\
    filter(Artist.id == 1).order_by(FacebookPost.created_at.desc()).\
    limit(5)
twq = db.session.query(t2.c.provider_post_id, t2.c.created_at,\
    literal("twitter_post", type_=db.String).label("post_type")).\
    join(TwitterUser).join((Artist,TwitterUser.artists)).\
    filter(Artist.id == 1).order_by(TwitterPost.created_at.desc()).\
    limit(5)
```

the queries indiviually work, i.e.

```
fbq.all()
```

gives a list of results which each have an attribute `post_type` that is "facebook_post". The same works for `twq.all()`. But as soon as I call

```
u = union(fbq.subquery().select(), twq.subquery().select())
db.session.query('provider_post_id', 'created_at', 'post_type').select_from(u).\
    order_by("created_at desc").all()
```

I get the following error:

```
InternalError: (InternalError) failed to find conversion function from unknown to text
```

I've tried using `literal_column` instead of `literal` to no avail. It seems like the issue is with adding this, since it works before adding the `literal`, but since they work individually, I'm really at a loss as to why this error is being raised. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This might be a postgres specific problem [See This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18073901/failed-to-find-conversion-function-from-unknown-to-text)

Comment: @RedBaron thanks! that did it. will post full solution below.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @RedBaron for his suggestion that this might be a [postgres specific problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18073901/failed-to-find-conversion-function-from-unknown-to-text), I was able to get this to work. I had to [`cast`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/expression_api.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.cast) the `literal` into a `db.String`:

```
fbq = db.session.query(t1.c.provider_post_id, t1.c.created_at,\
    cast(literal("facebook_post"), db.String).label("post_type")).\
    join(FacebookPage).join((Artist,FacebookPage.artists)).\
     filter(Artist.id == 1).order_by(FacebookPost.created_at.desc()).\
    limit(5)
twq = db.session.query(t2.c.provider_post_id, t2.c.created_at,\
    cast(literal("twitter_post"), db.String).label("post_type")).\
    join(TwitterUser).join((Artist,TwitterUser.artists)).\
    filter(Artist.id == 1).order_by(TwitterPost.created_at.desc()).\
    limit(5)
u = union(fbq.subquery().select(), twq.subquery().select())
db.session.query('provider_post_id', 'created_at', 'post_type').select_from(u).\
order_by("created_at desc").all()
```

works!