# ERROR: failed to find conversion function from unknown to text

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, type-conversion, union

There is an error on PostgreSQL that it gives on one of my select statements. I searched the web for an answer and came out empty handed. The answer given in another question did not suit my problem.

> ```
> ERROR:  failed to find conversion function from unknown to text
> ********** Error **********
> ERROR: failed to find conversion function from unknown to text
> SQL state: XX000
> ```

My query looks something like this:

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT 'string' AS Rowname, Data FROM table)
  UNION ALL (SELECT 'string2' AS Rowname, Data FROM table);
```

The point of doing this is to specify what the row is at one point. The string being the name of the row. Here is my desired output:

```
Rowname Data 
string  53
string2 87
```

Any possible way to fix this error?

Comment: postgresql doesn't usually need a FROM clause the way that Oracle (for example) does

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Update:** Type resolution in later versions of Postgres became smarter and this rule for [*UNION, CASE, and Related Constructs*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/typeconv-union-case.html) resolves it to text without explicit cast:

> 3. If all inputs are of type unknown, resolve as type `text` (the preferred type of the string category). [...]

```sql
SELECT 'string' AS rowname, data FROM tbl1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'string2', data FROM tbl2;
```

In older versions before Postgres 9.4 (?), or for non-default types you may still need to add an explicit cast like below.

---

Your statement has a couple of problems. But the error message implies that you need an **[explicit cast](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS)** to declare the (yet unknown) data type of the string literal `'string'`:

```
SELECT text 'string' AS rowname, data FROM tbl1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'string2', data FROM tbl2;
```

It's enough to cast in one `SELECT` of a `UNION` query. Typically the first one, where column names are also decided. Subsequent `SELECT` lists with unknown types will fall in line.

In other contexts (like the `VALUES` clause attached to an `INSERT`) Postgres derives data types from target columns and tries to coerce to the right type automatically.

Comment: Why is Postgresql wants us to strictly write the type? AFAIK, It should use the first query to determine the types for UNION statement and there is no other type in Postgresql that is defined as 'anythingOtherThanQuote'. Is it because Postgresql is not clever enough to infer the type or a design decision?

Comment: @burakemre: You seem to be missing that `rowname` is not derived from anything, but a genuinely new column. So the type cannot be inferred.

Comment: I don't understand why Postgresql can't execute this query: "SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'string') a UNION ALL SELECT 'string2'", when I take out the UNION ALL part, it works as expected. Postgresql already knows about string literals and I expect Postgresql to use "text" type for the string literal 'string'. Could you please explain what am I missing here?

Comment: @burakemre: For the record: this has later been fixed and works without explicit cast now.

Answer (score 2):

```
Select * from (select CAST('string' AS text) as Rowname, Data
  From table) Union all
 (select CAST('string2' AS text) as Rowname, Data
  From table)
```

[Reference](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createcast.html)

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the element of the anonymous row with `.f2` got the same error as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT (ROW(2,'David',32)).f2;
ERROR:  failed to find conversion function from unknown to text
```

So, I set `::VARCHAR(20)` just after `.f2`, then the error was solved as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT (ROW(2,'David',32)).f2::VARCHAR(20);
  f2
-------
 David
(1 row)
```