# How to get the first field from an anonymous row type in PostgreSQL 9.4?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, row, anonymous

```sql
=# SELECT row(0, 1) ;
  row
-------
 (0,1)
(1 row)
```

How to get `0` within the same query? I figured the below sort of working but is there any simple way?

```sql
=# SELECT json_agg(row(0, 1))->0->'f1';
?column?
----------
 0
(1 row)
```

No luck with array-like syntax `[0]`.

Thanks!

Comment: The `row` constructor produces an *anonymous record*. You can (ab)use `row_to_json` for the purpose. You can't index them with array operators because they aren't arrays. The fields may differ in type. Really, PostgreSQL's support for anonymous records is limited, and it's generally not a great idea to rely on them.

Answer (score 2):

Your row type is anonymous and therefore you cannot access its elements easily. What you can do is create a `TYPE` and then cast your anonymous row to that type and access the elements defined in the type:

```
CREATE TYPE my_row AS (
  x integer,
  y integer
);

SELECT (row(0,1)::my_row).x;
```

Like Craig Ringer commented in your question, you should avoid producing anonymous rows to begin with, if you can help it, and type whatever data you use in your data model and queries.

Comment: this could be a correct answer, at least works for me perfectly. If there is another method without the burden of declaring a new data type (like using an anonymous data type) it would be nice to see it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the first element from any row, convert the row to JSON and select f1...

```
SELECT row_to_json(row(0,1))->'f1'
```

Or, if you are always going to have two integers or a strict structure, you can create a temporary table (or type) and a function that selects the first column.

```
CREATE TABLE tmptable(f1 int, f2 int);
CREATE FUNCTION gettmpf1(tmptable) RETURNS int AS 'SELECT $1.f1' LANGUAGE SQL;

SELECT gettmpf1(ROW(0,1));
```

Resources:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-json.html
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-expressions.html

Comment: Note that the result of row_to_json is untyped. So sad that Postgresql doesn't have an accessor for anonymous records!

Answer (score 1):

The json solution is very elegant. Just for fun, this is a solution using regexp (much uglier):

```
WITH r AS (SELECT row('quotes, "commas",
and a line break".',null,null,'"fourth,field"')::text AS r)
--WITH r AS (SELECT row('',null,null,'')::text AS r)
--WITH r AS (SELECT row(0,1)::text AS r)
SELECT CASE WHEN r.r ~ '^\("",' THEN ''
            WHEN r.r ~ '^\("' THEN regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(right(r.r, -2), '""', '\"', 'g'), '([^\\])",.*', '\1'), '\\"', '"', 'g')
            ELSE (regexp_matches(right(r.r, -1), '^[^,]*'))[1] END
FROM r
```

When converting a row to text, PostgreSQL uses quoted CSV formatting. I couldn't find any tools for importing quoted CSV into an array, so the above is a crude text manipulation via mostly regular expressions. Maybe someone will find this useful!

Answer (score 0):

With Postgresql 13+, you can just reference individual elements in the row with `.fN` notation. For your example:

```sql
select (row(0, 1)).f1; --> returns 0.
```

See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS

Answer (score 0):

*Memos:

- You can easily access the element of an anonymous type row(record) different from an anonymous type row(record).

*[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36199437/how-to-access-record-elements-in-postgresql/77870310#77870310) explains how to access the element of a named type row(record).

For example, you have an anonymous type row(record) as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT ROW(2,'David',32);
     row
--------------
 (2,David,32)
(1 row)
```

Now, you can create `person` type as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TYPE person AS (
  id INTEGER,
  name VARCHAR(20),
  age INTEGER
);
```

Then, you can access the element of the anonymous type row with `person` type as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT (ROW(2,'David',32)::person).id;
 id
----
  2
(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT (ROW(2,'David',32)::person).name;
 name
-------
 David
(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT (ROW(2,'David',32)::person).age;
 age
-----
  32
(1 row)
```

Or, you can access the element of the anonymous type row(record) with `.fx` as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT (ROW(2,'David',32)).f1;
 f1
----
  2
(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT (ROW(2,'David',32)).f2::VARCHAR(20);
  f2
-------
 David
(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT (ROW(2,'David',32)).f3;
 f3
----
 32
(1 row)
```

*Memos:

- In an anonymous type row(record), the 1st element is `f1` and the 2nd element is `f2` ...
- Omitting `::VARCHAR(20)` from `f2` gets [the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25192813/error-failed-to-find-conversion-function-from-unknown-to-text/77872080#77872080).