# How to access record elements in PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, record, tablerow, greenplum

PostgreSQL v8.2 (Greenplum)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION util.retrec(OUT p1 date, OUT p2 boolean)
RETURNS RECORD
AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
BEGIN
 p1 := current_date;
 p2 := true;
 RETURN;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;

SELECT util.retrec();
```

This returns `(2016-03-24,t)` - how do I pull those two values out individually?

I can do it interactively with `SELECT p1,p2 FROM util.retrec();` but how do I assign the two values into two variables in a procedure? I tried this:

```
SELECT util.retrec() INTO r1, r2;
```

No luck, this tries to assign the record into r1.

Comment: Here is few examples: `select (retrec()).p1;` `select t.*, t.p1, t.p2 from retrec() t;` `select * from retrec();`

Comment: Ah, I think aliasing the function as t is the key to my problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT the_date, the_bool FROM util.retrec();
```

Just list the fields with their names, that ought to work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is several ways how to do it:

```
do $$
declare
  r1 date;
  r2 boolean;
  r record;
begin
  r := retrec();
  raise info '%', r;
  raise info '%', r.p1;
  raise info '%', r.p2;

  select * into r from retrec();
  raise info '%', r;
  raise info '%', r.p1;
  raise info '%', r.p2;

  select * into r1, r2 from retrec();
  raise info '%, %', r1, r2;
end; $$ language plpgsql;
```

Note that it was tested on PostgreSQL 9.5

Answer (score 0):

*Memos:

- You cannot easily access the element of a named type row(record) different from an anonymous type row(record).
- [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30337021/how-to-get-the-first-field-from-an-anonymous-row-type-in-postgresql-9-4/77872192#77872192) explains how to access the element of an anonymous type row(record).

For example, you create `person` table, then insert 2 rows into it as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE person (
  id INTEGER,
  name VARCHAR(20),
  age INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO person (id, name, age) 
VALUES (1, 'John', 27), (2, 'David', 32);
```

Then, you create `my_func()` function which returns a named type row(record) with `person_row` as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func()
RETURNS RECORD
AS $$
DECLARE
  person_row RECORD; -- Here
BEGIN
  SELECT * INTO person_row FROM person WHERE id = 2;
  RETURN person_row;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Or:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func()
RETURNS RECORD
AS $$
DECLARE
  person_row person%ROWTYPE; -- Here
BEGIN
  SELECT * INTO person_row FROM person WHERE id = 2;
  RETURN person_row;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then, calling `my_func()` gets a named type row(record) as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT my_func();
   my_func
--------------
 (2,David,32)
(1 row)
```

Now, you can access the element of the named type row(record) with `to_json()`, `to_jsonb()` and `row_to_json()` as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT to_json(my_func())->'id' AS id;
 id
----
 2
(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT to_jsonb(my_func())->'name' AS name;
  name
---------
 "David"
(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT row_to_json(my_func())->'age' AS age;
 age
-----
 32
(1 row)
```

*Memos:

- You can omit `AS` clause.
- [The doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) explains these functions.

In addition, you can use [trim()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) to trim `"` from `"David"` as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT trim(BOTH '"' FROM (to_json(my_func())->'name')::VARCHAR(20)) AS name;
 name
-------
 David
(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT trim(BOTH '"' FROM (to_jsonb(my_func())->'name')::VARCHAR(20)) AS name;
 name
-------
 David
(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT trim(BOTH '"' FROM (row_to_json(my_func())->'name')::VARCHAR(20)) AS name;
 name
-------
 David
(1 row)
```

*Memos:

- You can omit `AS` clause.
- Be careful, omitting `::VARCHAR(20)` gets [the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24751372/error-function-does-not-exist-and-hint-no-function-matches-the-given-name#77618099).