# Error 'failed to find conversion function from unknown to text' in sql query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to write a query to which if I pass some list of strings then it will check in particular table if those are present and return which are not present. I have written following query for that

```
SELECT temp_table.configuration_key FROM (#PLACEHOLDER) temp_table 
LEFT JOIN configuration c ON (c.configuration_key = temp_table.configuration_key) WHERE c.configuration_key IS NULL;
```

where #PLACEHOLDER will be formed dynamically like following

1 . if single string is passed #PLACEHOLDER will be

```
SELECT 'xyz' configuration_key
```

if more than one string is passed #PLACEHOLDER will be

```
SELECT 'xyz' configuration_key UNION ALL SELECT 'abc'
```

and so on.

Here 2nd query works fine but gives following error to 1st query

```
failed to find conversion function from unknown to text
```

configuration table has single column named configuration_key

Can anyone tell me whats wrong here. how to form query if there is only one string passed (i.e form a table with single element). I know I can do it by entire different query. But cant I do this using same type of query?

Comment: My guess here is that `NULL` is being cast to text somewhere along the way, and maybe you can't do that.  I don't fully understand what you are trying to do here though.

Comment: Help us help you - please share the structure (or preferably - the DDL) for the `configuration` table.

Comment: updated. configuration table has single column named configuration_key

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why this error is occurring with a single row subquery, but you can use explicit typecasting like

```
SELECT temp_table.configuration_key 
FROM (SELECT 'xyz'::text configuration_key
) temp_table 
LEFT JOIN configuration c ON (c.configuration_key = temp_table.configuration_key) 
WHERE c.configuration_key IS NULL;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c123d6/5)

Comment: You might want to look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18073901/failed-to-find-conversion-function-from-unknown-to-text then

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar error trying to do an in-DB_Write of just one record into the database (Failed to find conversion function from unknown to character-varying). My in-DB_Write tool gets its input directly from an in-DB_Connect tool with a custom query. I'm using the Redshift Bulk load driver for my writes (I don't see a way to configure a specific in-DB_Write tool to use the regular driver). The bulk load driver uses the COPY command to load from S3.

After reading your post, I suspected that the in-DB_Write tool is assuming the first row is a header row and that actual data starts from the 2nd row. So I did a union of the exact same SQL in my in-DB_Connect and it worked.

In summary, this fails:

```
Select Coalesce(Max(etl_process_control.process_id), 0) + 1 as process_id
, 1 as job_id
, getdate() as process_start_dttm
, to_timestamp('1899-12-31 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as process_end_dttm
, 'I' as process_status_cd
, 'In-Progress' as process_status_desc
, null as process_error_rsn
, -999 as rows_updated
, -999 as rows_inserted
, -999 as rows_deleted
, -999 as rows_failed
 From etl_process_control
```

But this works:

```
Select Coalesce(Max(etl_process_control.process_id), 0) + 1 as process_id
, 1 as job_id
, getdate() as process_start_dttm
, to_timestamp('1899-12-31 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as process_end_dttm
, 'I' as process_status_cd
, 'In-Progress' as process_status_desc
, null as process_error_rsn
, -999 as rows_updated
, -999 as rows_inserted
, -999 as rows_deleted
, -999 as rows_failed
 From etl_process_control
union
Select Coalesce(Max(etl_process_control.process_id), 0) + 1 as process_id
, 1 as job_id
, getdate() as process_start_dttm
, to_timestamp('1899-12-31 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as process_end_dttm
, 'I' as process_status_cd
, 'In-Progress' as process_status_desc
, null as process_error_rsn
, -999 as rows_updated
, -999 as rows_inserted
, -999 as rows_deleted
, -999 as rows_failed
 From etl_process_control
```

Lastly, you'll notice that I'm not using a union ALL, so the above query essentially returns only one row.... but somehow it works. This is not an ideal solution but gets around the error.